# Break text in TextBlock into lines on grid resize | Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, frontend, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have Grid with next two columns and one grid splitter (so, there are three columns). There is a TextBlock with some text inside one column and I want to break it into lines on column resize (to be more correct: break text into lines when column width is less than text one and restore to original when it fits).

There's my try:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, *">
  <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Chartreuse"/>
  <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="1" Background="Black"/>
  <Grid Grid.Column="2" 
        ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, *" 
        RowDefinitions="*, Auto, Auto, *"
        Background="LightGray">
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor et cetera a little bit long text">
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, there's no the most common mistake -- I've typed `TextWrapping="Wrap"`. I've also tried `WrapWithOverflow` and there was no difference.

Yeap, when I make fixed width like `Width="250"` it breaks text into lines, but that's not what I want. Must I use some events like `PropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

So, that's the only quick solution that I've found out. I know that better one exists (as always) and I'll edit this answer when I find it.

First of all name our `TextBlock` and `Grid`, and add event to the Grid like that:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, *">
  <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Chartreuse"/>
  <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="1" Background="Black"/>
  <Grid x:Name="GridName" Grid.Column="2" 
        ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, *" 
        RowDefinitions="*, Auto, Auto, *"
        Background="LightGray"
        PropertyChanged="GridName_PropertyChanged">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor et cetera a little bit long text">
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

than we write that event:

```
private void GridName_PropertyChanged(object? sender, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    switch(e.Property.Name) {
        case "Bounds":
            TextBlockName.Width = GridName.Bounds.Width*0.7;
            break;
    }
}
```

That's it.